# Html & Css: Why my javascript menu not work in IE 9?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `JavaScript` menu in my website with `ul` and `li` structure like this:

```
<ul id="...">
<li class="..."><a></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

[JsFiddle: Organization Chart Test](http://jsfiddle.net/SxunS/)

and in one page of my website, I have an organization chart, that made with same structure like my menu. 
The problem is in IE8 and IE9 and only in my organization chart page, the menu does not show its sub menu.
The problem will be solved when I delete some `li` and `ul` of my organization chart. This means that When I use more than 5 `ul` and `li` nested, The menu stop working.

My organization chart structure is so simple and not using `Javascript` for show or hide sub levels.
So please check this link and tel me why this happen?
[JsFiddle: Organization Chart Test](http://jsfiddle.net/SxunS/)

Comment: would you mind sharing the code and put it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you put your javascript code to examine..

Comment: @David Thomas This menu was created with an automated menu maker. This site uses a portal that do every thing automatically, We must make menu with that menu maker

Comment: This is online test: http://jsfiddle.net/SxunS/

Comment: This problem is unlikely to be solved with just a change to your HTML. It will almost certainly require a CSS change and, even more likely, a change to the JavaScript. Why does the menu-maker prevent you showing, or changing, the relevant code we've asked to see? Or was your comment based on something that I'm not understanding?

Comment: @DavidThomas No, The portal has a menu maker, that not showing final code, it generates the code run time, and it seems that the problem is not from javascript menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" above title in "<>"

Comment: My doctype is true exactly like what you say.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Snap of Ie9]

As you can check that it is working fine in IE9

Comment: It works for me too. What is not working, is right-menu of my website, when I add this chart into the page, my right menu is `ul` and `li` structed.

Comment: Any one know that if internet explorer has limits nested elements, or number of ul and li ?